# Don't understand this pytesseract initialization error

Tags: python, python-tesseract

Here's the code when I run it gives an error that it is not setting a variable in windows, but it is installed, there is also traindata, the solution on stackoverflow and github looked, there are some thoughts there, but they did not help me!

```
image = Image.open(create_path)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\Scripts\NewYorkCase__upwork__\new.py", line 60, in <module>
    main(driver, main_url)
  File "D:\Dev\Scripts\NewYorkCase__upwork__\new.py", line 53, in main
    get_ready_captcha = captcha_symbols_recognized(get_path)
  File "D:\Dev\Scripts\NewYorkCase__upwork__\new.py", line 40, in captcha_symbols_recognized
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image))
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 294, in image_to_string
    return run_and_get_output(*args)
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 202, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 178, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(status_code, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file \\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

Comment: It says `Failed loading language \'eng\'`. Did you install the corresponding language pack?

Comment: @feliks before writing a post here, I looked in google, all that was there did not help me!

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: Maybe you have more luck with the [installer from the UB Mannheim](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki)?

Comment: @feliks Yes, I installed it !!!!

Comment: @feliks can you suggest that you can use tesseract instead?

Comment: Did you set the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable correctly? Find the location of the language pack and set it like `os.environ['TESSDATA_PREFIX'] = r'C:\Path\To\Language\Pack'`